# Choosing functions within a phpclass

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to write a php script for a webstore that checks stock against different suppliers.  Unfortunately, the method of doing so is totally different for each supplier.  I've got a working routine for one, but rather than write half a dozen slightly different scripts, I'd rather use the same core and just have separate parsing routines for each supplier. That way I can add support for new suppliers by just writing a new parsing file and drop it in the right place.

I'd originally envisaged something like

```
$ref = "123456";
$supplier = new Supplier("CompanyOne");
$product = $supplier->getproduct($ref);
echo "Product with supplier reference " . $ref . " is " . $product["name"];
```

with Supplier being

```
class Supplier{
    function __construct($sup = "") {
        $f = "supplier_" . $sup . ".php";
        if (file_exists($f)) {
             include_once $f;
        }
    }
}
```

with getproduct() being within the included files, as it'd be different for each one.

I'm not sure, though, that this will work, as I think that the included routines will end up within the context of the constructor rather than the class itself.

This must be a common situation, but I've spent ages looking at includes, extends, callbacks, etc. and tried googling all manor of ways to describe what I want to do to find the best way of doing this, without coming up with anything.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  What is the best way to do this, bearing in mind I'd want to be including several different set of code which I won't know the names of until runtime?

Comment: The object-oriented way to do so is to implement inheritance or `Strategy pattern`. So, for each customer you either create a class that inherits from `Supplier` and overrides `getproduct` method (inheritance way), or have a generic `Supplier` that accepts a `GetProductStrategy` class (one of it's subclasses actually) to get the product (strategy aproach). I would go with inheritance approache, since it's simpler and less mind blowing (especially for junior level programmeers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not extend the class for each supplier.  Have your base class, then extend it for each supplier

```
class Supplier{
//do stuff
}

class Supplier_FirstCompany extends Supplier{
//do similar stuff, but different overwritten functions.
//still inherits functions from parent so not all need to be overwritten.
}
```

Then you could even set up a autoloader using `spl_autoload` that would load the files based on the requirements/namespace passed.  This is probably going to be the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Yup.  Sounds pretty much like something you can handle through inheritance.  Maybe toss an [Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) into the mix too.  The [Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) comes to mind as well, the description in the [PoEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) web page is a little brief.  But I imagine you might want some domain logic at some point rather than 5 'product' objects.

Comment: @ficuscr Don't get too much [Code Astronaut](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html) pills :)

Comment: Word.  Though in my experience I've suffered more from inheriting  [yo-yo problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem) and [anemic domain models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model) than over-engineering (or even decent engineering).  Good to know what is out there.  As for what is best to use of course depends on the project.

Comment: I like the astronaut link :-)

I'd looked at inheritance, and could load up all the different versions I guess, but from the examples, it seems I need to know which one to call?  e.g.
    $supplier = new Supplier_FirstCompany();
I'd be arriving at this point with company name in a variable, and it might not even be a valid option, hence the file_exists bit in the code up top.  

(bit of checking up later..)  Ah, class_exists() exists, and $x = new $foo(); seems to be a valid syntax.   I think this answers my questions.   Thank you all for the advice.